# django mutlipleChoiceField how to validate?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have the form below :

forms.py :

```
class enrolForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [('male','male'),('female','female')]
    students = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)
```

views.py :

```
 form = enrolForm(request.POST)
 if form.is_valid():
            print "creating student"
            exam = models.Exam.objects.get(name=examName)
            .
            .#more code .......
```

it NEVER  gets to ( `print "creating student"` ), the form is never valid  . why is that ?
how do i validate such a form 
please help

EDIT : 
it says in the form.errors : `<ul class = "errorlist"><li> students<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul><br>`
EDIT:

views.py :

```
def enrol(request,examName):
    print "EXAm naaame"
    form = enrolForm()
    allStudents = models.User.objects.filter(groups__name="students")
    myList = []

    for i in allStudents:
        myList.append((i,i))


    print allStudents,'33333333333333333333'

    form.fields['students'].choices = myList


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = enrolForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            exam = models.Exam.objects.get(name=examName) 
            for i in form.cleaned_data['students']:

                user= models.User.objects.get(username=i)
                exam = models.Exam.objects.get(name= examName)                
                models.Exam_Student.objects.create(user,exam)

            return render_to_response('enrol.html',RequestContext(request,{'form':form}))

    variables = RequestContext(request,{'form':form})
    return render_to_response("enrol.html",variables)
```

Comment: What do you get in `form.errors`?

Comment: it appears that `request.POST` is empty. Did you select a choice (male or female) before posting back the page?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing a post request and not a get request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with using a standard ChoiceField?

```
class enrolForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [('male','male'),('female','female')]
    students = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)
```

Also doing this to view the errors and letting us know would be helpful:

```
if form.is_valid():
    print "creating student"
    exam = models.Exam.objects.get(name=examName)
    ...
else:
    print 'ERRORS:', form.errors
```

Comment: i want a big menu filled with all students so the teacher will select the students from this list and add them to the class. do you think the standard choice field will be good for this task ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show your Student and Teacher models

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong. You should show your Student and Class models.

Comment: So, and correct me if I'm wrong, you are using the User model for students and the Exam model. Is there a Many2Many relationship on the Exam model to the User model?

Answer (score 1):

Your form isn't valid because the `students` field is required. That means you must select a student in order for `is_valid()` to be true.

**EDIT:** For some odd reason, I couldn't add new lines in my comments, so I'm adding this here...

For testing purposes, remove everything but the essentials and see what happens:

```
def enrol(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = enrolForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'Valid form'
        else:
            print form
    else:
        form = enrolForm()

    return render_to_response('enrol.html', {'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: i'm selecting all of the list elements before submitting. is that what you mean ?

Comment: That's not what I meant. The error your posted suggests no option is being selected. Why don't you post the entire views.py function. That will provide some clarity.